# Using Python Pandas, why is my vectorized gradient descent so much slower than my gradient descent using loops?

Tags: python, pandas, gradient-descent

Here is my vectorized version:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

alpha=.001

data = [    (2, 3),    (4, 7),    (6, 11),    (8, 17),    (10, 23),    (12, 31),    (14, 39),    (16, 49),    (18, 59),    (20, 71),    (22, 83),    (24, 97),    (26, 113),    (28, 131),    (30, 149),    (32, 169),    (34, 191),    (36, 214),    (38, 239),    (40, 266),    (42, 295),    (44, 326),    (46, 359),    (48, 394),    (50, 431)]


##CREATE EXAMPLES MATRIX
x_coordinates = [x[0] for x in data]
x_coords=[]
[x_coords.append([1,x]) for x in x_coordinates]
#Creates a list of all x-coordinates with a 1 column

examples=pd.DataFrame(x_coords).transpose()
#uses that list to create a dataframe.  Must transpose so it is dimsion 2,25.  rows are features, columns are specific examples.


##CREATE THETA MATRIX/VECTOR
theta_list = [1, 2]
theta = pd.DataFrame(theta_list).transpose()
#creates a df of dimension 1,2.  


##CREATE Y VECTOR/MATRIX
y_coordinates = [x[1] for x in data]
y=pd.DataFrame(y_coordinates).transpose()


deriv=pd.DataFrame([])
count=0
while (deriv != 0).all().all() and count <= 500000:

    length=len(data)

    #theta*X
    thetaX=theta.dot(examples)
    error=thetaX-y
    error_pt2=error.dot(examples.T)
    deriv=alpha*(1/length)*error_pt2

    theta=theta-deriv

    print(theta)
    count+=1
    print(count)
```

Here is my version made with loops:

```
total=0
th0=0
th1=0
alpha=0.001
deriv0=1
deriv1=1
count=0
while deriv0 and deriv1 != 0 and count<=1000000:
    total0=0
    total1=0
    #th0
    for i in data:
        
        hyp=th0+(th1*i[0])
        #print("Hyp is {}".format(hyp))

        total0+=(hyp-i[1])

    deriv0=(1/25)*total0
        

    
    th0temp=th0-(alpha*(deriv0))
    

    #th1
    for i in data:
        hyp=th0+(th1*i[0])

        total1+=(hyp-i[1])*i[0]

    deriv1=(1/25)*total1
    th1temp=th1-(alpha*(deriv1))

    th0=th0temp
    th1=th1temp

    th0temp=0
    th1temp=0

    count+=1


    print("Theta 0: {} \n  Theta 1: {} \n\n".format(th0,th1))


print(count)
```

When I run the vectorized version, it takes almost 10 times as long to run.  I would have expected using vectors would make this code much more efficient than running multiple loops.  What gives?  Is it just the computational overhead of Pandas which is making this run slower?  Maybe Pandas isn't suited for this sort of algorithm

Comment: Pandas is not designed for such calculations. It is built on top of NumPy to allow functionality that you do not clearly need and thus the computational overhead as you already mentioned. You should use NumPy instead to update your gradient descend.

Comment: On Pandas vectorization and speed of execution: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pandas-vectorization/

Comment: Ali bakhtiari, I've changed up my script to use numpy and it is still much slower than my looped version.